# How do I get the intersection of two graphs to be permanently displayed of the plot Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I two curves being plotted on the same graph in q Custom plot I used the Q mouse event function to display the coordinates of the mouse tip and so I can get the intersections manually.However I would like to get it automaticly and I would like it to be displayed permently on the graph as soon as the plot is made does anybody now how?